# Virtual core hotplug support in ARM Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, virtualization

I am trying to understand hotplugging support for virtual cores in ARM Linux SMP with Linux OS running as a virtual machine with reference to: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-hotplug.txt

If a Linux virtual machine is booted with max_cpus=2 on a quadcore ARM 32 bit processor corresponding to physical Core IDs 1 and 2, would core 0 (assuming its available) later be hot pluggable as:

echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/online

and core 3 as 
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/online

Or would the Linux kernel expect virtualization of core id from a lower layer( virtual machine monitor/hardware virtualization) to present core 0 as core 2?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your assumptions are here - it might possibly depend on the hypervisor, but certainly in the case of KVM, the vCPUs are normally scheduled on the available physical cores much like normal processes are, so there is no one-to-one mapping. I'm pretty sure you could run an 8-vCPU VM on a single-core host, provided you didn't want it to be fast.

Comment: @Notlikethat Thanks for your response. I guess assumption here is that unlike KVM hypervisor in question does not support scheduling of virtual machines dynamically on the available cores. Would the hotplug feature allow cores to be utilized effectively by virtual machine? if yes is there any virtualization of cpu IDs required by Linux.